# Wrapper for Hadoop Applications

Tags: java, hadoop, environment, facade

Does there exist a wrapper for Hadoop applications? I'm referring to a wrapper that would turn a Hadoop setup into a standalone application. I understand that this would defeat the purpose of Hadoop. However, this would assist in developing Hadoop applications quite immensely.

I know that the Hadoop Netbeans plugin allows for the creation of a local in-app Hadoop environment. However, I am looking for an application where you can have it proxy your Hadoop application in a single application environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is Hadoop in the CLASSPATH and it will run in local mode by default.

Answer (score 1):

on the apache hadoop wiki is an entry for debugging map reduce programs.
That might be an answer to you question

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDebugMapReducePrograms

There is also a blog by cloudera on how to run hadoop as a unit test
http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2008/12/testing-hadoop/

So you might be able to configure your environment to execute your map reduce program as a unit test to see what's going on

Comment: I do this with Cassandra and my web-service integration tests.

Comment: I'm not asking about how to debug a Hadoop application, I'm asking about how to turn a hadoop application into a single node application. [Yes this is counterintunitive] This is more for demonstration purposes than functional.

Answer (score 0):

Installing hadoop from the tar.gz file on a single node defaults to running everything on localhost. Format the hdfs (hadoop namenode -format) and start-all.sh should do it.